# How to create a boundary between two forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, boundary

i really don't know how to ask this, i have two forms (form1, form2) I have form1 inside form2:

```
    Dim ch As New Form1
    ch.TopLevel = False
    ch.Visible = True
    Me.Controls.Add(ch)
```

but the form1 when it passes the boundary of the form2:

[image]

I wanted to create a boundary from form2 so that form1 doesn't passed it. I try this code on form1:

```
Form1.Clip = New Rectangle(Form2.Location, Form2.Size)
```

But didn't work. I know my question It's a little bit messy, but hope you guys can help me with that.

Comment: why can't you use an `user Control` instead for another form?

Comment: @un-lucky I didn't understand what you're trying to say, i put the form1 inside form2 using `Me.Controls.Add(ch)` , but i want to move form1 within the boundaries of the form2. So if it hits the side of the form2, I want it to just stop.